# Containerization Frontend project cannot auto-refresh after code changes

Tags: reactjs, nginx, docker-compose, frontend, containers

I have a frontend project that was containerized by `docker` and `docker-compose.yml`, a few months ago. It was good and can automatically refresh the page `localhost:8080` after I made the code changes, Below shows the main code,

- docker-compose.yml

```yaml
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: ./docker/local/Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    networks:
      - myapp

  nginx:
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/app/mediafiles
    build:
      context: ./docker/local/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - myapp
```

- nginx configurations

```
upstream client {
    server client:3000;
}


server {
    location /ws {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

- .env file

```
WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0
FAST_REFRESH=false
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

- app.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

- package.json

```json
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.2.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

After I make code changes, I can get into the container, and the code does change inside and volume is working. I have no idea why the front end package will not refresh as it was few months ago. I re-installed docker and switched a new pc, but no luck still.

Can anyone provide me some insights?

Comment: Try to revert back to the code that was reloading. After reverting, if it does not work then it is something related with the package/application/tool update. Otherwise, make step by step changes and see where it breaks.

One thing I would suggest is to make sure that compose file and .env are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue of `webpack`, if we add `WATCHPACK_POLLING=true` to the `.env` file, the auto refresh will be working properly.